# Cross reference and caption for Tabularx?

Tags: captions, labels, captionof

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\title{Tabularx Test}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_1$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_2$} \\ 
\cline{2-3}
$a$ & 0 & 0  \\ \cline{2-3}
$b$ & $x$ & $y$   \\ \cline{2-3}
\end{tabularx}\vskip 1cm 
 \captionof{Figure}{test}
 \label{twobytwo}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

After searching a little bit, I thought \captionof works with tabularx. But the code does not work. I would like to make the caption and cross-reference work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not related with `tabularx`

Using `\captionof{table}{...}` (and adding the package `caption`) you can write

```
See the table \ref{twobytwox} or table \ref{twobytwo}.
```

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{caption}% added <<<<<

\title{Tabularx and Tabular Test}

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_1$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_2$} \\ 
        \cline{2-3}
        $a$ & 0 & 0  \\ \cline{2-3}
        $b$ & $x$ & $y$   \\ \cline{2-3}
    \end{tabularx}
    \smallskip
    \captionof{table}{test tabularx}
    \label{twobytwox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_1$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_2$} \\ 
    \cline{2-3}
    $a$ & 0 & 0  \\ \cline{2-3}
    $b$ & $x$ & $y$   \\ \cline{2-3}
  \end{tabular}
  \smallskip
  \captionof{table}{test only tabular}
  \label{twobytwo}
\end{center}
    
See the table \ref{twobytwox} or table \ref{twobytwo}.
    
\end{document}
```